# Change background color of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to change the background color of the vote button in below script ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
    <noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>​
```

The button is styled with class : 'pds-vote-button'

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/8/

This is what ive tried but does'nt seem to have any effect :

```
.pds-vote-button {
    background-color:blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Yes it is possible to do that..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/25LjE/53/):

Works when I did:

```
.pds-vote-button {
    background:blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to get the generated dom when the button is rendered, than apply your styles via javascript.
You can also replace images this way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the button background is from an image...
You need to change the image

This:

```
.pds-vote-button {
    background:blue !important;
}
```

overides the image css attribute.